# Basic CSS manipulation using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css

I'm currently learning JavaScript, but I'm very weak on the fundamentals. I'm trying to write a function that changes the background color when a link is clicked, can you please advise me on what I'm doing wrong?

```
<head>

<script type="text/javascript">

function change()
{
var abra = document.getElementbyId("body").style;
abra.background-color = "black";

}
</script>

</head>

<body>

<div id="body" style="background-color: red;">
<a href="#" id="test" onclick="return change()">Test</a>
sdfdsfsdfds

</div>

</body>
```

EDIT: For clarification, I was trying to change the background color of the DIV "body".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The property you're looking for is `backgroundColor`:

```
abra.backgroundColor = "black";
```

In general, Javascript uses the corresponding camelCase for CSS style properties. See a [list of some properties](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_style.asp) for examples.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
var abra = document.getElementbyId("body").style
abra.background-color = "black";
```

try

```
document.body.style.backgroundColor = "black";
```

---

```
document.getElementbyId("body")
```

looks for an element with ID body, and

```
abra.background-color
```

is the same as

```
(abra.background) - color
```

which will probably result in an error telling you there is no `var` named `color`.

Comment: This changes the bgcolor of the entire body, not just the div that happens to have the id "body". OP may want to achieve one or the other, just note that they're different.

Answer (score 0):

use camelCase:

```
background-color => backgroundColor
```

---

```
var abra = document.getElementById("body").style;
abra.backgroundColor = "black";
```

But if you want the body tag use:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0]
```

or

```
document.body // recommended
```